# flask-sqlalchemy intellisense/autocomplete

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, visual-studio-code, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm searching for a way to actually get intellisense for flask-sqlalchemy. All the answers I have found online seem to tell us how to suppress the errors (no Column or query instance members)(switch linters, ignore the class in pylintrc, etc...), but I find it very hard to belive that the most widely used ORM in python does not actually have linting support.

I am open to using pycharm or intellij community editions, but I'd rather stick with vs code, since I am a js developer who recently decided to learn python, and I'd like to stick with the tools I know and love. I hear that vs code has great python support, but sqlalchemy linting is a must!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/292#issuecomment-387292534 .. changing to flake8 worked for me

Comment: @SuperShoot I tried switching to flake8, all it did is suppress the errors.... However the mothods on the db object were still not shown by intellisense.

Comment: Are you using Jedi or the language server? Try the language server with `"python.jediEnabled": false`. If that doesn't do it then please open an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/python-language-server .

Comment: @BrettCannon doesn't work with `db.Column`

Comment: @TomSawyer it probably won't work until custom support is added since ORMs typically have magical methods which can't be inferred from their interfaces.

Comment: @BrettCannon yes, it's bad, i switched to use peewee instead :(